# How to debug the code of the radio interface layer of Android devices?

Tags: java, android, debugging, device, ril

I would like to know to debug the RIL code.I would like to know how to debug the code of the radio interface layer Layer (Ril) of Android devices. For example, if we use uiautomatorviewer.bat, we can get all the information about screen: text, class, package and others. So, I would like to know if is possible to debug the layers below (Ril, CP, etc.) the aplication layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the hardware is of your device.
If it is qualcomm devices, you can set
`persist.vendor.radio.adb_log_on 1`
to enable ril log printing in adb logs.

`adb logcat -v time -b radio >d:\radio.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can use APKTOOL and JADX
, JADX is a decopiler tool for java and APKTOOL is a tool for reverse engineering, try with that, good luck!